# 504.0 GatewayTimeout when migrating to umbraco 8

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco8

I try to migrate my V7.15.7 website to 8.1.x

I followed the guides / documentation / blog posts.

I made sure there are no  Obsolete document-types.

Then I installed the Pre-migration health checks and it says it ready for upgrade
[image]

Then I installed a fresh new Umbraco 8.5.5 website on my ftp, and after I logged in and made sure it works (the new empty 8.5.5 website) I logged out and changed the connection string in web.config to my old 7.15.7 database.

It started the migration process but after few minutes I got 504.0 GatewayTimeout

Then I tried the process again and after few minutes I got again 504.0 GatewayTimeout
So I tried to increase the Connection Timeout from 3600 to 33600, Connection Timeout=33600

Didn't help

```
<add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="Server=xxxxxx;Data Source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=33600;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

What's the reason I'm getting the 504.0 GatewayTimeout ?

I'm using Azure to host my website.

Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this article that I have recently written for the online Umbraco Skrift magazine about "How I upgraded my Umbraco v7 project to Umbraco v11"?

If you haven't, I recommend that you do so, as there are some critical steps that you need to follow in order to upgrade your projects successfully; otherwise, you'll end up seeing a lot of problems, like the one that you have seen.

https://skrift.io/issues/how-i-upgraded-my-umbraco-v7-project-to-umbraco-v11/

I have also talked at this year's Umbraco Community Day event about how to upgrade Umbraco v7 and v8 projects to the latest version of Umbraco v11. Please take a look at [this recording](https://youtu.be/AGtJPRKPMmc?t=10240), too.

Here are 12 steps that should help you doing your upgrades successfully;
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason - I tried to perform the migration direct on Azure, which is pretty much not possible ...

So instead, I had to Create Local SQL Server database on my computer:
[Create Local SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43355971/create-local-sql-server-database)

Then, I installed Umbraco locally:
[How to open Azure database .bacpac locally for local Umbraco website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75205413/how-to-open-azure-database-bacpac-locally-for-local-umbraco-website/75208841#75208841)

And I was able to migrate to 8, then 9, then 10, then 11 (don't skip steps..)